# Getting Sublime + xDebug to work on Debian

Tags: debian, php, mysql, debugging

I have been trying to get sublime and xdebug to work on debian, but have had no luck.  I can't seem to find any debian specific guides.  I have tried using the ubuntu based guides, but they don't work on debian as the xdebugging step through does nothing.

Does anyone know where I can find a debian based guide on how to get this configured.  If not, can someone help me here?  The ubuntu based guides all seem to go smoothly, but when I try to debug, it doesn't, and doesn't return any reason for not working.

Answer (score 0):

How are you connecting all of this? I found this simple client that connects with XDebug from Sublime. I believe you'd need to use something like this to facilitate the connection.

- https://github.com/Kindari/SublimeXdebug